# Pegar Elemento dinâmico no JSON

Tags: javascript, json

tenho o seguinte json

```
{
    "error": false,
    "installments": {
        "visa": [{
            "quantity": 1,
            "installmentAmount": 500.00,
            "totalAmount": 500.00,
            "interestFree": true
        }, {
            "quantity": 2,
            "installmentAmount": 261.28,
            "totalAmount": 522.55,
            "interestFree": false
        }]
    }
}
```

Este objeto visa, pode ser alterado dependendo da chamado porem apenas este objeto, pode vir como bradesco, itau, etc.

Existe uma forma de acessar as informações deste objeto sem ser pelo nome explícito dele (installments.visa)?

De alguma forma jogar em uma variavel assim:

```
var cartao = installments.(truquemagico);
```

E acessar os dados assim:

```
console.log(cartao[0].totalAmount);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há uma forma sim. Primeiro você pode descobrir qual é *key* do objeto em `obj.installments` usando [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Dessa forma, independente do que estiver ali (visa, master, etc) será salvo em uma variável. Então é possível acessar essa chave pelo colchetes `[]`, ficando `obj.installments[prop]` - onde *prop* é o chave que foi descoberta.

```js
var obj = {
    "error": false,
    "installments": {
        "visa": [{
            "quantity": 1,
            "installmentAmount": 500.00,
            "totalAmount": 500.00,
            "interestFree": true
        }, {
            "quantity": 2,
            "installmentAmount": 261.28,
            "totalAmount": 522.55,
            "interestFree": false
        }]
    }
}

// descobrir a key
var prop;
for (property in obj.installments){
  prop =  property;
}

console.log(obj.installments[prop][0].totalAmount);
```